# How to append a list in Python if it has been decorated in a class?

Tags: python, oop

So the code below uses decorators for the variable `_states`. I want to append the list inside my class, so I wrote the method `state_my_append`. But the problem is it isn't working.

On the other hand, if I call my variable outside of my class, it runs just fine. I have placed the outputs of the print statements as comments.

```py
class State():
    def __init__(self):
        self._states = []

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self._states
    @state.setter
    def state(self, val):
        self._states = val

    def state_my_append(self, val):
        self._states.append(val)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self._states[idx]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        self._states[idx] = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return " -> ".join(str(state) for state in reversed(self.states))


s = State()

s.states = [1, 2, 3]
print(s) # 3 -> 2 -> 1

s.state_my_append(5)
print(s) # 3 -> 2 -> 1

s.states.append(5)
print(s) # 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
```

Comment: You're using the word `state` instead of `states` in some places. Do `@property def states(self):` and `@states.setter def states(self, val):`

Comment: @dumbPotato21 That was it, if you make it into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Looks like we both figured out the issue at the same time :)

Comment: @Matt Ah looks like it. But you missed the one at the getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight edits make it work:

```
class State():
    def __init__(self):
        self._states = []

    @property
    def states(self):
        return self._states
    @states.setter
    def states(self, val):
        self._states = val

    def states_my_append(self, value):
        self._states.append(value)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self._states[idx]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        self._states[idx] = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return " -> ".join(str(state) for state in reversed(self.states))


s = State()

s.states = [1, 2, 3]
print(s) # 3 -> 2 -> 1

s.states_my_append(5)
print(s) # 3 -> 2 -> 1

s.states.append(5)
print(s) # 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1

3 -> 2 -> 1
5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
5 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
```